# Linux lsof Need help parsing output

Tags: linux, bash, awk, lsof

I'm using the following command on a linux system:

```
lsof -i -n | egrep '\<ssh\>'|awk '{print $8,$9}'
```

and it produces output like this:

```
192.168.199.52:ssh->192.168.199.254:17598 (ESTABLISHED)
192.168.199.52:ssh->192.168.199.254:17598 (ESTABLISHED)
192.168.199.52:56448->69.168.130.22:ssh (ESTABLISHED)
192.168.199.52:56449->69.168.130.22:ssh (ESTABLISHED)
192.168.199.52:56454->69.168.130.22:ssh (ESTABLISHED)
192.168.199.52:56458->69.168.130.22:ssh (ESTABLISHED)
192.168.199.52:56460->69.168.130.22:ssh (ESTABLISHED)
192.168.199.52:56468->69.168.130.22:ssh (ESTABLISHED)
192.168.199.52:ssh->192.168.199.254:56671 (ESTABLISHED)
192.168.199.52:ssh->192.168.199.254:56671 (ESTABLISHED)
192.168.199.52:ssh->192.168.199.254:56672 (ESTABLISHED)
```

I want to extract just the IP Address from the left side and just the IP Address on the right side of the "->" field.  How can I easily extract those two fileds and reassemble them into the following format:

```
192.168.199.52->192.168.199.254
```

Comment: better show the original output of `lsof -i -n`, because otherwise you will end up with something like `lsof | egrep | awk | awk`, which is tremendously unefficient.

Comment: Why are you printing $9 when you don't want it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

something like:

```
lsof -i -n | awk '$9 ~ /:ssh(-|$)/{ gsub(/:[^-]*/, "", $9); print $9 }'
```

or perhaps with $8 instead of $9.

awk command details:

```
$9 ~ /:ssh(-|$)/ {           # when ":ssh" is at the end of field 9 or
                             # followed by an hyphen
    gsub(/:[^-]*/, "", $9);  # remove all the semi-colon followed by characters that
                             # are not an hyphen from the field 9
    print $9                 # and print it
}
```

Comment: fedorqui was right - I don't want field $9 - not sure what I was contemplating at the time.  The above worked awesome, I just changed $9 to $8.

Comment: @Rick: just for information, in my system, it only works with the 9th field.

Comment: @Rick: I have made a mistake. ":ssh" can be before the hyphen too, take a look at the corrected answer.

Comment: To avoid field numbering issues for various versions of `lsof`, you can use the [`-F` option with `n` field specifier.  See man lsof(8): OUTPUT FOR OTHER PROGRAMS](https://www.mankier.com/1/lsof#Output_for_Other_Programs).  You can then just pipe to `grep -E '^n'` to filter them.   If you want more output, you'll have to pass in different field specifiers into `-F`, and then parse out the info.

Examples: `sudo lsof -F 'n' -n -i:22 | grep -E '^n'`
Or with more fields, terminated by null `0` chars: `sudo lsof -F 'PnLt0' -n -i:2222`